# google api client callback is never called

Tags: android, google-api-client

I am trying to get the last known location using google services API, but after I build the GoogleApiClient, no callback method is ever fired.

My activity looks like that :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentObserver, SessionSpotListObserver,
                                                        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{

//Objects used for the location API
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    // Request code to use when launching the resolution activity
    private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 1001;
    // Unique tag for the error dialog fragment
    private static final String DIALOG_ERROR = "dialog_error";
    // Bool to track whether the app is already resolving an error
    private boolean mResolvingError = false;
    public static final String STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR = "resolving_state";
    //Request code to use when launching the activity to fix the connection to google API
    private static final int REQUEST_SOLVE_CONNEXION = 999;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//We make sure that google play service is available on the device
         if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            //We get a connection to the Google Play Service API to get the location of the user
            buildGoogleApiClient();
         }
         else {
             GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this),
                     this,
                     REQUEST_SOLVE_CONNEXION); 
         }
}

@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
         if (mResolvingError) {
                // Already attempting to resolve an error.
                return;
            } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    mResolvingError = true;
                    result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                // Show dialog using GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()
                showErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode());
                mResolvingError = true;
            }
        }

        // The rest of this code is all about building the error dialog

        /* Creates a dialog for an error message */
        private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
            // Create a fragment for the error dialog
            ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
            // Pass the error that should be displayed
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DIALOG_ERROR, errorCode);
            dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
            dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "errordialog");
        }

        /* Called from ErrorDialogFragment when the dialog is dismissed. */
        public void onDialogDismissed() {
            mResolvingError = false;
        }

        /* A fragment to display an error dialog */
        public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
            public ErrorDialogFragment() { }

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Get the error code and retrieve the appropriate dialog
                int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ERROR);
                return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode,
                        this.getActivity(), REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onDialogDismissed();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
         mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
         Log.d("API Connection", "The API has connected and the last location is :" + mLastLocation);
            if (mLastLocation != null) {

            }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * Creates the connexion to the Google API. Once the API is connected, the 
     * onConnected method is called.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)    
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
    }
```

I placed breakpoints on all callback methods, that is how I know that none is called.

Because at this stage I am not using Google Map Api, I did not register my app to get a key. Do I need to do that even if I just get the location ?

Don't hesitate to tell me if you need more info.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You never call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` after building your `GoogleApiClient`. Your `onCreate()` should instead be:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Note that there is no need to call `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` if you are using `GoogleApiClient` as `connect()` includes that check as well.

Comment: I didnt know the connect method performed the check automatically. Good catch.

Comment: Thank you mate. It hurts my feelings a bit to have missed the connect() method in the Api client =) Maybe google should make it more obvious int the training documentation because I really was under the impression that the Builder was making the connection.

Comment: THanks i recently found the issue and this answer helped me out :)

Comment: omfg, I read google docs for over an hour and they never use this method. Thank you!

Comment: For me it was perfectly fine before some hours in development, Connection & then score post. But then it never ever calling success/failure callback. What could be reason. Is there any limit on number of of connection using an email-id ? I'm using _com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'_ & _com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0_.

Comment: So in my case now _GoogleApiClient.connect()_ not working at all, what could be reason, please suggest !!

Answer (score 0):

consider calling `onLocationChanged()` and passing it's Location parameter to `mLastLocation` for continuous location update when the user location changes. Also you might want to reduce the drain on your battery by setting `LocationRequest()` interval and distance to a small value.